# Two external monitors using macOS and Windows on a MacBook Pro 13”

Tags: display, bootcamp, usb, hardware-recommendation

I am in the process of setting up my desktop space and would like some guidance on products to purchase.

I am looking to buy two external monitors and a dock that will allow me to use my macOS and Windows Boot Camp partition on MacBook Pro 13” (2019) with two USB-C ports.

I essentially want to be sure that I will be able to utilize both operating systems when I purchase the new hardware. I have encountered mixed reviews about what will work with Boot Camp. I am willing to sacrifice display quality for speed as I will be using various types of statistical software and ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check with the manufacturer to *ensure it works with the OS on the Bootcamp partition*.

There is no Bootcamp “compatible” hardware because Bootcamp isn’t an operating system, it’s  functionality built into your Mac.

So, you have to check to see if the dock, displays, and any other ancillary devices are compatible with macOS and Windows 10 (for example).

That said, docks and displays rarely have specific OS drivers.  Get quality ones of each and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on the monitors. For example, if you need the traditional Mac displayports, you would buy a [Thunderbolt 3 Dual 
DisplayPort Adapter](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3ADP2DP/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shoppingengine&utm_campaign=googlebase&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_fD6g5rD5wIVhMDACh1CTAwHEAQYAiABEgKx8fD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: Right so what you’re saying is the dock depends on the monitor, that makes sense. But my main concern is running both operating systems. For me, I don’t care if it’s displayport, HDMI, etc, as long as it can run bootcamp on both monitors too.

Comment: Literally any consumer market monitor (i.e. not Apple XDR Display or other professional gear) will work. Bootcamp allows you to start the Mac with a different operating system. I have the feeling you are getting a bit confused by Bootcamp tbh...

Comment: No I run bootcamp now, it’s just hardware upgrades are new for me. I wanna make sure I’m not buying something that’s not gonna work on both OS’s. If you’re saying that any monitor and dock will work, that’s great! Thank you for the clarity

Answer (score 0):

No wait, you can't use bootcamp like that.
Bootcamp is designed to allow you to change your operating system while the computer boots.

Nothing allows you to swap *purely* between operating systems that way. you can use software that runs Windows in OS X with hardware virtualization, a huge step up from the software virtual machines of old.

There are three good options: 
Parallels, VMWare Fusion, and VirtualBox, 
the last of which has the advantage of being free.

Comment: I don’t think you understood the question; the OP isn’t trying to use both operating systems *simultaneously* or switch them on the fly.